# How do I get a geography field to populate with a radius value

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, geolocation, geography

I have a SQL database field that accepts a geography value and I'm trying to fill that value with a radius of a geo point.  I'm looking to be able to perform this update to the table via SSMS so a SQL script will be helpful. For example I have the following details

```
Longitude: -87.6648
Latitude: 41.6747
```

I was able to calculate the geopoint from the following sql statement and save it to my geocode field in my location table

```
Update Locations 
    set geocode = geography::STGeomFromText ('POINT(' + @long + ' ' + @lat + ')', 4326)
where ID = @LocationID
geopoint = 0xE6100000010C3C4ED1915CD644405F984C158CEA55C0
```

now I'm trying to get the value for 25 mile radius of this geopoint and save that value to another geography value in the location table.  I will use this value in other areas of my code to determine suppliers located in this 25 mile range.

expecting a value that looks like this 
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

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try STBuffer(). Like so:

```
declare @metersPerMile = 40234;
select geocode.STBuffer(25*@metersPerMile)
From locations;
```